# Parse value of option into html attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, selly-api

I'm currently trying to make a ecommerce website that uses selly.io. But I recently got stuck on trying to change the product ID ( thats used to tell selly.io what the user is buying ) depending on the size of the product they want to buy.

This is the part of the code I'm talking about:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 p-b-30">
    <div class="p-r-50 p-t-5 p-lr-0-lg">
    <h4 class="mtext-105 cl2 js-name-detail p-b-14">
        Hoodie
    </h4>

    <span class="mtext-106 cl2">
        €50,00
</span>
    <p class="stext-102 cl3 p-t-23">Nulla eget sem vitae eros pharetra viverra. Nam vitae luctus ligula. Mauris consequat ornare feugiat.
    </p>

    <div class="p-t-33">
        <div class="flex-w flex-r-m p-b-10">
            <div class="size-203 flex-c-m respon6">
                Size
            </div>
            <div class="size-204 respon6-next">
                <div class="rs1-select2 bor8 bg0">
                <select class="js-select2" name="time">
                    <option>Choose an option</option>
                    <option>Size S</option>
                    <option>Size M</option>
                    <option>Size L</option>
                    <option>Size XL</option>
                </select>
                <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-w flex-r-m p-b-10">
        <div class="size-203 flex-c-m respon6">
            Color
        </div>
        <div class="size-204 respon6-next">
            <div class="rs1-select2 bor8 bg0">
                <select class="js-select2" name="time">
                    <option>Choose an option</option>
                    <option>Blue</option>
                    <option>White</option>
                    <option>Grey</option>
                </select>
                <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-w flex-r-m p-b-10">
        <div class="size-204 flex-w flex-m respon6-next">
            <div class="wrap-num-product flex-w m-r-20 m-tb-10">
                <div class="btn-num-product-down cl8 hov-btn3 trans-04 flex-c-m">
                </div>

                <input class="mtext-104 cl3 txt-center num-product" type="number" name="num-product" value="1">
                <div class="btn-num-product-up cl8 hov-btn3 trans-04 flex-c-m">
                </div>
            </div>

            <button data-selly-product="3cffe13b" class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-addcart-detail">Add to cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I am trying to change this id:

```
<button data-selly-product="3cffe13b"
```

Depending on what the user selects here:

```html
<select class="js-select2" name="time">
    <option>Choose an option</option>
    <option>Size S</option>
    <option>Size M</option>
    <option>Size L</option>
    <option>Size XL</option>
</select>
```

I've tried parsing the option selected option to a javascript variable called value:

```html
<div class="size-204 respon6-next">
    <div class="rs1-select2 bor8 bg0">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getComboA(selectObject) {
                var value = selectObject.value;  
            }
        </script>
        <select class="js-select2" name="time" id="comboA"onchange="getComboA(this)">
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="3cffe13b">Size S</option>
            <option value="M">Size M</option>
            <option value="L">Size L</option>
            <option value="XL">Size XL</option>
        </select>
        <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then storing that value in a cookie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        createCookie("value", value, "1");
    });

    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        var expires;
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        } else {
            expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
    }
</script>
```

To then make that value be echoed in the data-selly-product:

```
<button data-selly-product="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["value"])) echo $_COOKIE["value"]; ?>" class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your actual problem, so far you show us what you have done (what is good), but you did not tell what your problem is (other than that you got stuck).

Comment: @Aldert Okay I did

Comment: Hello @CHC, thanks for the update, I was reviewing questions, I cannot help you (do not have the skills). Will upvote your questions because you do a good effort asking a question. I hope you get some support soon.

Comment: Thank you very much @Aldert

Comment: You are overthinking this I'm afraid. I'm assuming your selly data comes from php in the first place and it populates the `select` values. You just need to pass the selected value via ajax to your backend when clicking the button. Read a bit on the topic and see if it helps and come back if you have trouble. Or let me know if I'm completely wrong.

Comment: The thing I'm trying to to is just parse the value from the Size S option into the "data-selly-product" tag so that it would look like this: ```<button data-selly-product="3cffe13b" class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04">Add to cart</button>```

Comment: Well to set the value of an attribute you can use the setAttribute function. See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just set the `data-selly-product` attribute of the `button` you have to use the [`.dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). Quoting from the link:

> The name of a custom data attribute in JavaScript is the name of the
>   same HTML attribute but in camelCase and with no dashes, dots, etc.

```js
function getComboA(selectObject) {
  const button = document.querySelector('button.js-addcart-detail');
  button.dataset.sellyProduct = selectObject.value;
  console.log(button);
}
```

```html
<select class="js-select2" name="time" id="comboA" onchange="getComboA(this)">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="3cffe13b">Size S</option>
  <option value="M">Size M</option>
  <option value="L">Size L</option>
  <option value="XL">Size XL</option>
</select>

<button class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-addcart-detail">Add to cart</button>
```

Instead of using a `onchange` attribute, I'd suggest moving this to a separate file and use a listener instead. This allows you to better separate logic from presentation and you can add multiple listeners to the same element. You only have to make a small adjustement in t he code:

```
document.getElementById('comboA').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const button = document.querySelector('button.js-addcart-detail');
  button.dataset.sellyProduct = this.value; // `this` is the element receiving the event
});
```

Comment: I don't know why but your answer did exactly what I wanted it to do and I thought it would work that way but when I now click on the add to cart button nothing happens, it only works when I hardcode the data-selly-product in.

Comment: @CHC The only thing I can think of is if the click handler has a static Node cached, but I *think* it should work regardless. Hard to know without seeing any code.

Comment: Should I upload the entire project somewhere?

Comment: @CHC No, just the functions involved and accompanying html code will do (even the specific click handler should be enough), no one is going to pour over the whole thing. You can create a fiddle or ask a new question demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This is what happens when its hardcoded: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkpr0vac/3/  This is with your method implemented : https://jsfiddle.net/Lkpr0vac/1/

Comment: @CHC Ok, there are a couple of things: I removed the data-* attribute completely and was setting it dynamically, but selly api must be using it to set the handler so it has to be present, even if empty: `<button data-selly-product class="..."`. Also, the `js-addcart-detail` class is missing, so my `button` selector fails. Otherwise I think it does what it should.