# How to parse value of option into input value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm sorry this question is kind of a duplicate of this question: [Parse value of option into html attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080118/parse-value-of-option-into-html-attribute) but I don't know how to change the answer there to my problem. I am trying to do the same thing just I'm trying to not parse it into a "data-selly-product" I'm trying to put it into "value".

This is the code for the button where the values should be inserted to:

```
<form class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04" name="PrePage" method = "post" action = "https://scotest.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx"> <input class="js-addcart-detail" type = "hidden" name = "LinkId" value ="" /> <input type = "image" src ="//testcontent.authorize.net/images/buy-now-gold.gif" /> </form>
```

The rest is exactly the same as with the other problem

I've tried changing this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getComboA(selectObject) {
const button = document.querySelector('button.js-addcart-detail');
button.dataset.sellyProduct = selectObject.value;
console.log(button);
}
</script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getComboA(selectObject) {
const button = document.querySelector('form.js-addcart-detail');
form.value = selectObject.value;
console.log(button);
}
</script>
```

Error message in Developer Console:

```
ReferenceError: form is not defined
```

But that doesnt work.

Comment: In the example HTML you've provided, `button.js-addcart-detail` is not present. "*... that doesnt [sic] work*" also isn't terribly descriptive - can you include any error messages you're getting in your developer console?

Comment: To set the value of the attribute you can use the setAttribute function. See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstood your question**, then this is what you want to achieve. You basically want to set the selected option's `value` on a `hidden` input fields `value`.

```js
function getComboA(selectObject) {
  const input = document.querySelector('input.js-addcart-detail');
  input.value = selectObject.value;
  console.log(input);
}
```

```html
<select class="js-select2" name="time" id="comboA" onchange="getComboA(this)">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="3cffe13b">Size S</option>
  <option value="M">Size M</option>
  <option value="L">Size L</option>
  <option value="XL">Size XL</option>
</select>

<input class="js-addcart-detail" type="hidden" name="LinkId" value="" />
<button class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04 js-addcart-detail">Add to cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use :

```
     `<input class="js-addcart-detail" type = "hidden" .....`
```

So your code should be :

```
     `const input = document.querySelector('input.js-addcart-detail');`
```

Or you can give an id to you element and get it like that:

```
     `<input id="myId" class="js-addcart-detail" type = "hidden" .....`
```

then JS should be :

```
     `const button = document.querySelector('#myId');`
```

For mode details https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Hopes help you !